# Use jwks_uri from OIDC configuration to check JWT tokens signature

Tags: pac4j

The headless (Clojure) application I'm working on must check calls to its REST API bear a valid signed JWT token (direct client). Said token is delivered to callers by a private authentication service very similar to [the one described here (Facebook OIDC)](https://www.facebook.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/). I'm trying to get Pac4j (6.0.0-RC7) to take this OIDC configuration and use the value from field `jwks_urk` to return whatever is necessary (supposedly an instance of `org.pac4j.jwt.credentials.authenticator.JwtAuthenticator`) to check token signatures.

Based on the Javadoc, source code, [docs](https://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/openid-connect.html), and [many examples](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/validating-jwt-access-tokens) I can either:

- turn my configuration URL into an instance of `org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration` but can't get a `JwtAuthenticator` out of it or get the value of `jwks_uri`.
- directly instanciate a `JwtAuthenticator` based on the content of field `jwks_uri` that I've manually extracted from the OIDC config.

Is there a path I'm missing that would get me an instance of `JwtAuthenticator` directly from the OIDC configuration URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can't instantiate a `JwtAuthenticator` directly from an OIDC configuration. You may want to use the `JWKHelper`.

Feel free to submit a PR to the project.